# LINQ to SQL: IQueryable - string contains - method has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

Dear LINQ or linq2sql experts, can you help me to solve this case?

I have Book class, every book has a List and what I want is to find the Books whose Authors lastnames in the Authors list contain a particular searchAuthor string, as follows:

```
string searchAuthor = "foo";
IQUeryable books = BookStaticRepository.SelectAll();

books.Where(r => r.Authors.Any(x => searchAuthor.Contains(x.lastname, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

What I get it this error:

***Method 'Boolean Contains(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)' has no supported translation to SQL.***

**I already tried the same but using IEnumerable, and it worked**. I had to switch to IQueryable for performance issues... I need it to work with IQueryable.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unless you've changed your collation on the server, TSQL performs case insensitive searches so you don't need the overload on the Contains.

Comment: you are right, "StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase" was not required as I was creating a query to the DB and not to an IEnumerable, but even removing that I had the same error message that there was no supported translation to SQL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi guys thanks I found the solution myself:

```
books.Where(r => r.Authors.Any(x => x.lastname.Contains(searchAuthor)));
```

The mistake -I think- was that I was doing a sort of "opposite work": I was saying like "the lastname has to contain the searchAuthor string" and not viceversa (the lastname has to contain the SearchAuthor string... which now gives me the results I'm expecting).

The funny thing is that the exact same query I posted in my initial question was working fine using IEnumerable.

Comment: Well, MiG gave you the correct answer above - that should probably be the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi Frank, not really, I already tested that way before asking on stackoverflow and I got an error (with and without StringComparison). I just tested it again to be sure. See the difference btw (x => searchAuthor.Contains(x.lastname)) -not working: error "Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for the String.Contains method."- and (x => x.lastname.Contains(searchAuthor)) -working-.

Comment: @firepol - Ah I see... I missed the contains parameters were the wrong way round.

Comment: That it works as IEnumerable and not as IQueryable is expected. IEnumerable is performed in memory. All methods your program knows can be used. IQueryable is performed on the database side, only fairly simple standard functions can be performed there. The database does not know the StringComparison class, and your linq-to-sql translator that is used when the IQueryable is enumerated does not know how to translate it (which is exactly the error message)

Answer (score 5):

That particular overload of `Contains` does not work, but ignoring the `StringComparison` will make it translate to SQL, which will generate a `LIKE %SearchInput%`. This will be case-insenstive by default, unless your DB is set to be case senstive.

Like so:

```
string searchAuthor = "foo";
IQUeryable books = BookStaticRepository.SelectAll();

books.Where(r => r.Authors.Any(x => searchAuthor.Contains(x.lastname)));
```